# Angularjs - should I use it for this app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frameworks

I've lately realized that I would like to jump into AngularJS framework. I was developing with jQuery for few years now.

I want to create some application that helps user to modify webpage dom (some sort of browser WYSIWYG editor). It just loads page normally and adds some custom sidebar with tools - like managing css styles, adding new elements, editing curent content. So basically there is only one view added - sidebar. Main part is normal page that has nothing to do with my editor.

I'm in the middle of work and I was doing it with jQuery - but it requires a lot of same, repeating DOM manipulation.

So do you think guys it's good to make it with AngularJS?

I would have features like:

- a lot of inputs for various css styles that will modify styles of selected item in real item (last clicked item would be active or something like this)
- options like duplicate item, remove item, restore default styles, sort with other items
- adding new items ( for now I'm doing it with jQuery UI Dragging and Sorting)

and so on that you can imagine it would need.

My goal is to focus on business logic of this (and there is a lot of this) and leave all those events, checking item propeties, updating them etc to framework.

Also what other frameworks are good for this? jQuery is great for DOM modifications but in this case all of them are very similar to each other.

Thanks.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the dom lib you use but your ability to identify pattern, code them & extend them to suit every specifities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, I would say that Angular is not likely to be a good fit for this project. Most of the power of Angular comes from directives, which are generally applied by adding attributes to your markup. Since the main bulk of the markup in the page is out of your control, much of what angular does won't help you modify the underlying page. Angular might help you with your own UI, but most likely jQuery would be more useful for applying the styles to the elements on the original page.

Comment: I can modify oryginal content - detect some types of elements and add attributes to them and save it. Also new elements that are added by editor I can control (their html and attributes). So - pages created by editor from start I've got almost full control about their html, pages that are alredy working and need to be modified I must auto recognize. Do this change your point?

Comment: Thinking some more about your situation, I'd say that Angular is great when you want to keep the DOM in sync with some model. It seems like in this case, the DOM itself IS the model and you'll be making changes to it and persisting those changes. In my opinion, jQuery is the gold standard when it comes to directly manipulating the DOM, especially since in this case the resulting markup and styling won't be dependent on jQuery to be valid markup when not in editing mode. Angular is a really nice framework but you will probably find arbitrary DOM editing easier in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I think angular is great for any client side coding, automatic updating of async data & organization of code in an MVC structure. Just give it a try.